# What is this OCaml function returning?

Tags: ocaml

As I understand it, OCaml doesn't require explicit `return` statements to yield a value from a function. The last line of the function is what returns something.

In that case, could someone please let me know what the following function `foo` is returning? It seems that it's returning a stream of data. Is it returning the `lexer`?

```ml
and foo ?(input = false) =
   lexer
      | 'x' _
         -> let y = get_func lexbuf
            get_text y
      | ',' -> get_func lexbuf
      | _ -> get_text lexbuf
```

I'm trying to edit the following function, `bar`, to return a data stream, as well, so that I can replace `foo` with `bar` in another function. However, it seems that `bar` has multiple lexers which is preventing this return. How can I rewrite `bar` to return a data stream in a similar way that `foo` appears to?

```ml
let bar cmd lexbuf =
   let buff = Buffer.create 0 in

   let quot plus =
      lexer
         | "<" -> if plus then Buffer.add_string b "<" quot plus lexbuf

   and unquot plus =
      lexer
         | ">" -> if plus then Buffer.add_string b ">" unquot plus lexbuf

   in
   match unquot true lexbuf with
      | e -> force_text cmd e
```

Comment: Slight correction here, it's not the last _line_ of a function that gets returned, it's the last _value_ that gets evaluated in each _branch_ of the function.

Answer (score 2):

First, your code is probably using one of the old camlp4 syntax extension, you should precise that.

Second, `foo` is returning the same type of value as either `get_text` or `get_funct`. Without the code for those functions, it is not really possible to say more than that.

Third,

```
  Buffer.add_string b ">" unquot plus lexbuf
```

is ill-typed. Are you missing parentheses:

```
  Buffer.add_string b ">" (unquot plus lexbuf)
```

?

Comment: Thank you. ```get_text``` and ```get_func``` return strings, so that must be how ```foo``` also returns a string. Are you able to see what ```bar``` is returning?

Comment: Not sure if there should be parentheses or not, I didn't write this code and it's quite old. ```unquot plus lexbuf``` does seem to be representing inputs into a function call, so parentheses would probably improve readability without changing the final compiled code.

Comment: You might be missing a semi-colon `;`? You should really try to provide a fragment that compiles, it would remove many layers of guesses and hypotheticals. Any way if `get_text` returns a string `foo` returns a string, and the "stream" of data features is provided elsewhere.